# Count function for ordered set/map

Tags: c++, stl

`container.count(val)` - gives the frequency of "val" in container. Why count need to traverse till end for each value "val" in ordered set. My point is for ordered set/map, elements will be in order so we may get the final value of count even before reaching the end. I understand, this doesn't apply for other containers (list, vector etc.).

Example :-

```
set<int, less<int>> s{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int cnt = s.count(2);  // return 1
```

Since set/map can have count as 0 or 1, once i reach 2 it should break the loop rather than traversing till end. Also, compiler knows the comparator (less or greater). Same can be done for multiset/multimap, only difference is count can be >1.

Comment: I'm confident that a `std::set`'s or `std::map`'s (and their multi versions) have an optimized `count()` that does not do what you believe it does.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/ this is algorithm function though, not sure about set/map member function, how it's implemented.

Comment: That link has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with map's `count()` method. This is a standalone `<algorithm>`. You have a generic algorithm here, for an arbitrary sequence defined by iterators, and methods in C++ library's classes that have the same name.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik that's what i said in previous comment, i couldn't find member function count for set/map, hence speculating if it's implemented that way?

Comment: The standard guarantees `log(b.size()) + b.count(k)` for `std::map::count(k)` and `std::set::count(k)`.

Comment: You haven't looked very hard: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count

Comment: yeah, got it :)

Answer (score 2):

From [n4618](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4618.pdf), § 23.2.6, page 848

#### Associative container requirements

> Expression: `b.count(k)`
>   Return type: `size_type`
>   Assertion/note/pre-/post-condition: returns the number of elements with key equivalent to `k`
>   Complexity: `log(b.size()) + b.count(k)`

This means that, by definition, these functions cannot count every element of the container before deciding what the count of `k` is.